# Jquery .hide and .html stopped to work

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form in Fancybox lightbox window with Ajax content. 2 days ago I instaleld Jquery 1.11.0 and discovered that there is a problem with this form.

The script sends request to send.php, gets the response and closes Fancybox window. For test porposes I included alert(msg) and it always shows the correct message.

The problem is that stopped to work **.html and .hide**. The script doesn't show received message in #note and doesn't hide #fields:

```
$("#fields").hide();
$(this).html(msg);
```

Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){$(document).ready(function(){                                         
    $("#sendb").submit(function(){
        var str = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/send.php",
            data: str,
            success: function(msg){
                $("#note").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){
                    $("#fields").hide();
                    $(this).html(msg);

                });
                alert(msg);
                setTimeout( function() {$.fancybox.close(); },2000); 
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
    //});
})});

</script> 
<div id="note"></div>
<div class="dv1">
<div id="fields">
<form id="sendb" name="sendb">
<input type="text" name="text" value="" id="text"> <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" /></form></div></div>
```

Comment: Don't use `.ajaxComplete`, just put your code in the success function.

Comment: And for test purpose, use your console, don't alert message, alert is modal and can interfer with code's behaviour

Comment: yes, without .ajaxComplete it works. Why you didn't post as a answer?